# Bixby javascript - How do I get user current location

Tags: javascript, bixby, bixbystudio

How do I get user current location in javascript action?
when I try to use `$user.currentLocation` I get an error

Comment: format your code section properly and try to provide your error logs if possible , also tag your question accurately.

Answer (score 1):

In your Action file, include the following code to get the CurrentLocation object which is part of the viv.geo library capsule that you will have to import. Refer to this post for instructions on how to import capsule libraries https://stackoverflow.com/a/53747472/10409637

```
computed-input (myLocation) {
  min (Required) max(One)
  type (geo.CurrentLocation)

  compute {
    if ($user.currentLocation.$exists) {
      intent {
        goal: geo.CurrentLocation
        value-set: geo.CurrentLocation { $expr ($user.currentLocation) }
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

In your javascript function, you can then access the CurrentLocation object as `console.log(myLocation)`, the result will be

```
latitude:21.334342
longitude:-88.89106
$id:null
$type:viv.geo.CurrentLocation
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this function

this code snippet does not work for stackOverflow then go to Codepen

try on: https://codepen.io/lucassoomago/pen/YBzOoW

```js
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else { 
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
  x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ReferenceError: "getCurrentPosition" is not defined.