# How can get the user Current Location and Address in bixby

Tags: javascript, bixby

I want user's current location and location address on sigle-line from layout.

but i don't know how to get the locations, address. please help me

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend exploring the Geography Library capsule ([viv.geo documentation](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/library.geo))

The viv.geo library capsule gives you the ability to figure out a user's current location and perform a number of actions with that information.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54308425/bixby-javascript-how-do-i-get-user-current-location